# How can I force turbo boost work constantly in Ubuntu?

Tags: intel, tools, overclocking, turbo-boost

In windows I  have a tool which I just turn on and have turbo boost constantly on my i5 in laptop.. Unfortunately i can't overclock my cpu over bios. Can anybody recommend any tool for Ubuntu ? I'm not worry about ventilation and electricity.

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Turbo-boost is on "all the time" by default in the default `ondemand` CPU governor.

But that doesn't mean the clock speed is always the turbo boost's level all the time and certainly not for all cores. Turbo boost allows the CPU to scale up one or two cores (depending on the CPU) to an overclocked level on demand. This will happen in Ubuntu.

What you can't (and shouldn't) do is try to turbo boost while overclocking. I'm not even sure it's possible. You'd be mixing two things that shouldn't be mixed.

But what you can do is set a manual overclock in your BIOS. CPU scaling will probably still happen but that isn't an issue because ondemand is just as fast as the performance governor in most situations. You [can set it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20271/how-do-i-set-the-cpu-frequency-scaling-governor-for-all-cores-at-once) if you wish.

Comment: sorry, made a mistake. I mean I want to force cpu work on maximum speed always. For ex. if usual 2.5 and turbo boost give 3.2. for 4 cores. Would be really cool have 3.2. In windows  ThrottleStop do this. Unfortunately provider of laptop's bios don't give features for overclocking.  Seems this impossible.