# Dell Optiplex 5050 and 3020 MFF Power Adapter

Tags: dell, power-management

First some background:

I picked up one Dell Optiplex 5050 and two 3020 MFF desktops, without power adapters.  They were super cheap and figured why not?  I looked at Dell's website, which is selling the power adapters for $45 and said no effin way.  So I bought a compatible adapter off eBay for $15.  Right voltage, amperage, barrel connector, thought I would be good to go.  It arrived, I plugged it in, and everything worked...  sort of.  It seemed much slower than it should have been.  I tried the other 2, same thing.  Everything was working, but felt slow.  I installed Windows 11 and it was slow as well.  However, that when I realized it was running at 800Mhz, rather than the 2.9Ghz.  After doing some research, I found out that if you arent using a real Dell compatible power adapter it will put the computer in low performance mode for ***"safety."***  This cannot be disabled in BIOS, as far as I can tell.  However, I did find software on Windows called ThrottleStop that allowed the machine to run at full speed.

How can I do this in Ubuntu, as I am not paying $45 to Dell for a 65W power adapter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set the CPU frequency scaling governor for all cores at once?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20271/how-do-i-set-the-cpu-frequency-scaling-governor-for-all-cores-at-once)

Comment: @mikewhatever I will reinstall Ubuntu and check it out.  Love how there are 10 answers and everyone arguing about which one is right...

Comment: Well, welcome to the real world outside of North Korea. :~)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the correct Dell Adapters on Amazon for half the price from Dell.  Why Dell sells the same product at two different prices?  Who knows?  But I bought them from Amazon and they work.